# Angularjs ng-show method getting called way too many times

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat loop which loops over 3 events. In each event, I want to check to see if the logged in user, is a player of the team the event is associated with.

The problem is, my code is getting inside `is_player()` around 30 times each time the page is loaded. This obviously causes problems because it's trying to hit the GET method like 30 times in less than a second.

Why is this being called so many times and how can I fix this issue?

```
<div class="list-group" ng-repeat="event in events">

     <div ng-show="is_player(event.team_id, profile.id)">
         ...
     </div>
</div>
```

Controller method

```
/**
     * Checks if a user is a player on the team. Need this method so that managers of a team can't rsvp if they're only a manager and not a player
     * @param team_id   - The team id of the event that we want to check if the user plays on
     * @param user_id   - The user that we want to check if they're a player of a team
     */
    $scope.is_player = function(team_id, user_id) {

        console.log('in is_player');

            $http.get(baseUrl+'v1/teams/' + team_id + '/players' + apiKey)
                .success(function(response) {

                    console.log("getting a team's players");
                    var players = response;

                    // Loop through all the players on the team
                    for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {

                        //If the current player in the loop's user id matches what was passed in
                        if(players[i].user.id == user_id) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } 

                    $scope.error = null;
                })
                .error(function(response) {
                    $scope.success = null;
                    $scope.error = 'An error occurred looking for your events. Please try again later.';
                }); 

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: why are you looping through the events in $scope.is_player?

Comment: @victorswx I was about to ask that. And also this: if you need the playerIds to handle view-logic, then shouldn't you return an array of playerIds for each event as part of the initial data load for events?

Comment: Oh good point. I'm not anymore. I updated the code in my question.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I suppose that's not a bad idea. But in general i'm still curious why `is_player()`  would get executed so many times in an `ng-show`.

Comment: are you still getting the same error? Also, is .list-group div inside another block?

Comment: If i'm setting the events variable multiple times, how would that matter in an ng-show? Also, how is .list-group div relevant to this question?

Comment: @Stewie awesome links to other questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `ng-show` is being run on every digest cycle because of the data binding. Consider doing data pruning of events, either on the server or on the front end when you get the data back of "events" from the server. In general, you want to make functions like ng-show light functions, or simply correspond to boolean values on a property.